# Math on CSS Style Attributes in Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, css

I am modifying CSS attributes of a div in vanilla JS. When I grab the value, it's a string with px on the end, like '340px' so I can't just add a number directly. I end up doing this:

`element.style.top = element.style.top.split("px")[0]+pixelsToAdd;`

It works fine, but it feels hacky. Is there a more direct way to grab and set the value, or is this it?

Comment: parseInt(value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `parseInt()` to convert it to an integer:

```js
var px = "302px";
console.log(parseInt(px));
```